# set marker at autocomplete search location

Tags: android, google-maps

I have onPlaceSelected(Place place) method in main activity I want to use this in map fragment, to set marker position on selected location.Map fragment is a fragment in main activity(in Navigation drawer),How can I do this
here is my code..

```
 @Override
public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Place Selected: " + place.getName());

    // Format the returned place's details and display them in the TextView.
    mPlaceDetailsText.setText(formatPlaceDetails(getResources(), place.getName(), place.getId(),
            place.getAddress(), place.getPhoneNumber(), place.getWebsiteUri(),place.getLatLng()));

    final CharSequence name = place.getName();
    final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
    final LatLng location = place.getLatLng();
    AppConstants.SHOW_SEARCH_LOCATION=address;
    AppConstants.SHOW_SEARCH_LATLNG=location;
    Log.d("placedetails",name+","+address+" "+location);

    CharSequence attributions = place.getAttributions();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(attributions)) {
        mPlaceAttribution.setText(Html.fromHtml(attributions.toString()));
    } else {
        mPlaceAttribution.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place.getLatLng()));
```

to your `onPlaceSelected` method.

`mMap` is a map instance that you can get like this:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        this.mMap = map;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have getLagLng() in main activity.how do I get it in MapActivity extends Fragment class

Answer (score 0):

After you pressed the `placeSelectedListener` from `autoCompleteFragment` , you need to call back the map loaded.

Situation: After you search the location you wanted at `AutocompleteSupportFragment`, and then you press the specific place you wanted, the camera will zoom to that place and marked it.

Method setAutoCompleteFragment

```
 private void setAutocompleteFragment() {
        // Specify the types of place data to return.
        assert autocompleteFragment != null;
        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG));
        // Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull final Place place) {
                if (place.getLatLng() != null) {
                    buttonSubmit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    latitude = place.getLatLng().latitude;
                    longitude = place.getLatLng().longitude;
                    name = place.getName();
                // Creating a marker
                final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(place.getLatLng()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Setting the position for the marker
                markerOptions.position(place.getLatLng());

                // Setting the title for the marker.
                // This will be displayed on taping the marker
                markerOptions.title(name);

                // Clears the previously touched position
                mMap.clear();


                mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapLoaded() {
                        // Animating to the touched position
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place.getLatLng()));
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place.getLatLng(), 13.3f));

                        // Placing a marker on the touched position
                        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    }
                });

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Status status) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

And I put in the onCreate. Like this.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_package_location);
        view = findViewById(R.id.view_auto_complete_support_fragment);
        buttonSubmit = findViewById(R.id.button_submit);
        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
        autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
    setViewOnCancel();
    setButtonSubmit();

    mapFragment.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    // Initialize the SDK
    Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.google_api_key));
    // Create a new Places client instance
    Places.createClient(this);
    setAutocompleteFragment();
}
```